# Function to set properties of an object of a class composition

Tags: python, python-3.x, class, composition, keyword-argument

I would like construct a class composition that includes a function `set_props` for setting the instance variables of components.
The application for this is in defining new objects for drawing in matplotlib. One example is that I would like to have a function `drawMyArrow` that draws an arrow with possibly different colors (and other specifications) for its head, tail, and arc. I would like to be able to pass various specifications for the head, tail, and arc via keyword arguments in `drawMyArrow`. I haven't worked with classes before, but reading up on this online, I believe that the best way to solve my problem is to define a class `MyArrow` that is a composition of some classes `ArrowHead` and `ArrowArc`.

To illustrate my problem, I am using a toy example (that I also used for a previous question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54611325/managing-and-renaming-instance-variables-of-class-compositions?noredirect=1#54611461)). Let's define a class `Room` that is a composition of the classes `wall`, `window`, and `door`.

```
class Door:
    def __init__(self, color='white', height=2.3, width=1.0, locked=True):
        self.color = color
        self.height = height
        self.width = width
        self.locked=locked

class Window:
    def __init__(self, color='white', height=1.0, width=0.8):
        self.color = color
        self.height = height
        self.width = width

class Wall:
    def __init__(self, color='white', height=2.5, width=4.0):
        self.color = color
        self.height = height
        self.width = width

class Room:
    def __init__(self):
        self.door = Door()
        self.window = Window()
        self.wall = Wall()
```

If I want to have a function for `Room` that can set properties of its components, I can do something like this:

```
def set_windowprops(r, color=None, width=None, height=None): 
    if not color==None: r.window.color=color
    if not width==None: r.window.widht=width
    if not height==None: r.window.height=height
    return r
```

But if I decide to add more instance variables to `Window`, I would have to go back to this function and add the new instance variables. Can I write `set_windowprops` so that it automatically accepts all instance variables of `Window` as keywords?

Ideally, I would like to write a function like this:

```
def set_props(r, windowcolor=None, windowwidth=None, windowheight=None,
              doorcolor=None, doorwidth=None, doorheight=None, doorlocked=None,
              wallcolor=None, wallwidth=None, wallheight=None): 
    if not windowcolor==None: r.window.color=windowcolor
    if not windowwidth==None: r.window.widht=windowwidth
    if not windowheight==None: r.window.height=windowheight
    if not doorcolor==None: r.door.color=doorcolor
    if not doorwidth==None: r.door.widht=doorwidth
    if not doorheight==None: r.door.height=dooorheight
    if not doorlocked==None: r.door.locked=doorlocked
    if not wallcolor==None: r.wall.color=wallcolor
    if not wallwidth==None: r.wall.widht=wallwidth
    if not wallheight==None: r.wall.height=wallheight
    return r
```

but without the need of hardcoding all instance variables of components into the function.

I was looking into using keyword dictionaries like so:

```
window_vars = getNamesOfInstanceVariables(Window) #TODO
window_kwargs = {}
for v in window_vars:
    window_kwargs[v] = None

def set_windowprops(r, **kwargs):
    for kw in kwargs:
        if not kwargs[kw]==None:
            r["window"][kw] = kwargs[kw] #TODO
    return r
```

Two issues keep me from getting this to work:

(1) In the last line, I am pretending that `r` is a dictionary (of dictionaries) and using dictionary syntax to assign a value to `r.window.kw`. But that doesn't work because `r` is an instance of `Room` and not a dictionary. What would be the syntax for setting instance variables if the name of the component class and the name of the instance variable are given as strings?

(2) I have tried using `inspect` to write `getNamesOfInstanceVariables`, but I am unable to get it to work robustly. Many classes in `matplotlib` inherit from base classes. I would like `getNamesOfInstanceVariables` to return *all* instance variables that a user can set for an object of this class. For example, the class `FancyArrow` in `matplotlib` has `Patch` as base class and instance variables `head_length` and `head_width`. So I would `getNamesOfInstanceVariables(FancyArrow)` to return `['head_length','head_width', *listOfInstanceVarsForPatch]`.

**EDIT**

Let me add a bit of background on why I am asking for a dynamical way to write these functions. Let's say I have finished my script and it includes the classes `Window`, `Door`, `Wall` and many class compositions of these three. One of these many class compositions is `Room`. This class `Room` has ten hardcoded `set_` functions that look like this:

```
def set_windowcolor(r, color):
    r.window.color = color
    return r
```

I now decide that I want to add another instance variable to the class `Window`. For example,

```
class Window:
    def __init__(self, color='white', height=1.0, width=0.8, open=False):
        self.color = color
        self.height = height
        self.width = width
        self.open = open # new attribute of Window
```

Similar to all the other instance variables of window, this new attribute of `Window` should be customizable in all classe compositions that contain a `Window`. So I would go through my code, find the class `Room` and add a function

```
def set_windowopen(r, open):
    r.window.open = open
    return r
```

I would also have to look for all other class compositions that contain a `Window` and update them manually as well. I don't want to do this because it is a lot of work and I am likely going to overlook some class dependencies in the process and introduce bugs into my code. I am looking for a solution that either

- generates `set` functions for single properties (e.g. `set_windowcolor`) automatically in `Room` for all instance variables of `Window` or
- automatically adjusts the list of keyword arguments in `set_windowprops` or `set_props`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is what I would do

```
class Room:
    def __init__(self, kw_door=None, kw_window=None, kw_wall=None):
        if kw_door:
            self.door = Door(**kw_door)
        else:
            self.door = Door()
        if kw_window:
            self.window = Window(**kw_window)
        else:
            self.window = Window()
        if kw_wall:
            self.wall = Wall(**kw_wall)
        else:
            self.wall = Wall()
```

effectively you are accepting a dictionary that will be unpacked into the instance creation, and when the class definition gets new attributes, they too will be unpacked if they are found in the passed dictionary.

Answer (score 0):

To answer you first question. If you want to set `window` attribute of `r` and `kw` attribute of that `windows as in your example, you cat do the following:

```
setattr(getattr(r, "window"), kw, kwargs[kw])
```

You get attribute named `window` of `r`. And for that `windows` attributes set its own whose name is in variable `kw` to a new value from `kwargs[kw]`. As your line has attempted.

But to be perfectly honest, why a function with many possible arguments would be preferred over just accessing/setting the attributes themselves? Or in other words, on the face of it, it looks more complicated then it needs to be.

As for you second question. You should be also able to just use `dir()` to get list of instance attributes, but yes, inherited attributes will be getting in your way and I am not immediately sure if there is an elegant way around it (i.e. not walk the inheritance tree and do the pruning yourself). But if you genuinely wanted to dynamically walk attributes of an instance that are subject to for instance setting through a function, I'd say add a (class) attribute defining what those are to be for each type rely on that as a defined interface.

---

side note: There is only one instance of `None` (and `True` and `False`) and it can be tested for identity (not just equality) and since it reads a little better you would normally see `if somevar is not None` instead of `if not somevar == None`.

Comment: Thank you for this! Regardless of how many arguments I use per function, the key problem is the same: If I change the instance variables in a component class `Windows`, I always need to change at least one function in the class `Room` too (regardless of whether that function is `set_props` or `set_window_props` or the single property setter `set_windowcolor`). What I want is the class `Room` adjust dynamically to changes in the class `Window`.

Comment: That relation of changing `Window` attribute affecting `Room` is not immediately obvious to me from the question. I can try to help, if I understand. Could you perhaps elaborate a bit more?

Comment: Thank you! I edited my question to give some motivation for the problem that I would like to solve.